# Name of first property in JSON

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net

I am querying a REST endpoint for data. The result can be one of two kinds of documents

In simplified versions, these are

1.

```
{
    "Feature": {
        "CreationDate": "2018-07-12T09:22:37.068Z",
        "_CreatedAt": "Jul 12, 2018",
        "ObjectID": 236769828012,
        "ObjectUUID": "5a4fa66b-a81b-48c3-afdc-b7ad8c4d4d1b",
        "VersionId": "36",
        }
}
```

2. 

```
{
    "Initiative": {
        "CreationDate": "2018-07-12T09:22:37.068Z",
        "_CreatedAt": "Jul 12, 2018",
        "ObjectID": 236769828012,
        "ObjectUUID": "5a4fa66b-a81b-48c3-afdc-b7ad8c4d4d1b",
        "VersionId": "36",
        }
}
```

So the structure of the documents are identical - apart from the first property - which I do not now at runtime.

My question:

How do I get the value for that property?

My code to extract simply uses the Newtonsoft component to deserialize the result from the API into a `dynamic` construct.

```
static void GetItemByProject(string projectId)
{
    //var uri = ...;
    response = GetData(uri);
    dynamic itemData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Result);
}

static async Task<string> GetData(string uri) 
{
    return await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
}

static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

I know that I can use reflection or cast the result of the DeSerializeObject-method to a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` result and iterate over the keys, but that seems really cumbersome.

Is there a more elegant way to do what I want?

Comment: Just FWIW, you'd be out of luck if there were a second property. [JSON](https://www.json.org/) describes objects as *"An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs."* (JavaScript, on the other hand, has introduced order to them. JSON still hasn't, and likely won't.) But since you're just dealing with a single property, you're in good shape. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, I know ... but in my case I am 100% sure that there will never be a second property :-)

Comment: You can use `JObject` and `Json.Linq`

Comment: If you only have to deal with _exactly two_ property names, you can probably have a wrapper class having both properties defined. When you deserialize, only one of the two properties will have value. You also can make the two properties private and add `[JsonProperty]` to both, then expose the non-null one via a public property. This is quick impl tbh, not sure if it is _elegant_ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`Json.Linq`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) for that, just get the first property and deserialize its value

```cs
var result = JObject.Parse(response.Result);
var value = result.Properties().FirstOrDefault()?.Value.ToObject<Response>();
```

Where `Response` class can be the following (just an example, you can use any model that you want)

```cs
public class Response
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string _CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public long ObjectID { get; set; }
    public string ObjectUUID { get; set; }
    public string VersionId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @JesperLundStocholm Does it answer your question, do you need more details or explanation?

Comment: Hi Pavel as mentioned to @Roman below I want to avoid creating wrapper classes to handle this. I am looking for a solution to work on the JSON response directly :-)

Comment: @JesperLundStocholm What stops you to use `JObject` properties and values directly then?

Comment: nothing ... I will have to look into JObject to see if it works for me, so thank you for that suggestion. I just want to use it without needing to maintain wrapper classes as the "Response"-class above :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have

```
public class Root
{
    public FeatureOrInitiative Feature { get; set; }
    public FeatureOrInitiative Initiative { get; set; }

    public static Root FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
}

public class FeatureOrInitiative
{
    [JsonProperty("CreationDate")]
    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_CreatedAt")]
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ObjectID")]
    public long ObjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ObjectUUID")]
    public Guid ObjectUuid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("VersionId")]
    public long VersionId { get; set; }
}
```

This is it, actually. We just call our Deserializer and get what we need for both variants:

```
Root itemData = Root.FromJson(response.Result);
// Feature or Initiative is null
```

Comment: Hi @Roman, I have deliberately tried to avoid having C# DTO's (wrapper classes) to handle this. At the moment I do not know which properties I need and do not want to maintain a wrapper class as well.